# Copy altered CSV Data to new CSV

Tags: powershell, csv

The whole point of this issue is going to be: How to copy data from one CSV to another **without** knowing/listing the headers of the original CSV.
The cmdlet I'm building is meant to convert a report from CSV to a spreadsheet eventually. And if I write the column headers to the code, each time somebody changes the report, the code will break and it would have to be updated.

The steps I would take right now:

```cs
# Import the Source CSV. Gonna pull data from this later.
$SourceCSV = Import-Csv -Path $reportSourceCSV -Delimiter ";"

# Remove NULL characters, white spaces and change comma separator to semicolon.
(Get-Content -Path $reportSourceCSV | Where-Object {-not [string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($PSItem)}).Replace('","',";") | Out-File -FilePath $TMP1

# Import the modified new temp CSV.
$Input = Import-Csv -Path $TMP1 -Delimiter ";"

# Take existing CSV file headers and append some new ones. Rename a long column name.
((($GetHeaders = foreach ($Header in $SourceCSV[0].PSObject.Properties.Name) {
"`"$Header`""
}) + '"column4"','"column5"','"column6"') -join ";").Replace("VerylongOldColumnName","ShortName") | Out-File -FilePath $TMP2

foreach ($Item in $Input) {
    "`"$($Item.column1)`";`"$($Item.'column2')`";`"$($Item.column3)`"" | Out-File -FilePath $TMP2 -Append
}
$exportToXLSX = Import-Csv -Path $TMP2 -Delimiter ";" | Export-Excel -Path $Target -WorkSheetname "reportname" -TableName "tablename" -TableStyle Medium2 -FreezeTopRow -AutoSize -PassThru
$exportToXLSX.Save()
$exportToXLSX.Dispose()
Remove-Item -Path $TMP1, $TMP2
```

This works! But I don't want to create infinite amount of different reports and just as many different logic blocks to process all these reports.

So this is as far as I was able to get trying a more dynamic way of processing the report CSVs:

```
(Get-Content -Path $reportSourceCSV | Where-Object {-not [string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($PSItem)}).Replace('","',";") | Out-File -FilePath $TMP1
$import = Import-Csv -Path $TMP1 -Delimiter ";"

$headers = ($import[0].PSObject.Properties.Name).Replace("VerylongOldColumnName","ShortName")
$headers | Out-File -FilePath "C:\TEMP\test.csv"

foreach ($item in $import) {
    for ($h = 0; $h -le ($headers).Count; $h++) {
        $($item.$($headers[$h]))
    }
}
```

Now, this works... kind of. If I run the script like this, it shows me the output I want, but I was NOT able to export this to CSV.
I added `Export-Csv` to this line: `$($item.$($headers[$h]))` so this particular line would look like this:

```
$($item.$($headers[$h])) | Export-Csv -Path $Output -Delimiter ";" -Append -NoTypeInformation
```

And this is the error I get:

```
Export-Csv : Cannot append CSV content to the following file: C:\TEMP\test.csv.
The appended object does not have a property that corresponds to the following
column: column1. To continue with mismatched properties, add the -Force parameter,
and then retry the command.
At line:11 char:36
+ ... ers[$h])) | Export-Csv -Path $Output -Delimiter ";" -Append -NoTypeIn ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (column1:String) [Export-Csv], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotAppendCsvWithMismatchedPropertyNames,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ExportCsvCommand
```

If I add `-Force` parameter, the output will be the headers and a bunch of empty lines.

As little as I understand, is that the output is for some reason a string? To my knowledge everything should be an object in PS, unless converted to string (Write-Host cmdlet being an exception). And I don't really know how to force the output back to being objects.

---

Edit: Added sample source CSV

```
"Plugin","Plugin Name","Family","Severity","IP Address","Protocol","Port","Exploit?","Repository","DNS Name","NetBIOS Name","Plugin Text","Synopsis","Description","Solution","See Also","Vulnerability Priority Rating","CVSS V3 Base Score","CVSS V3 Temporal Score","CVSS V3 Vector","CPE","CVE","Cross References","First Discovered","Last Observed","Vuln Publication Date","Patch Publication Date","Exploit Ease","Exploit Frameworks"
"65057","Insecure Windows Service Permissions","Windows","High","127.0.0.1","TCP","445","No","Individual Scan","computer.domain.tld","NetBIOS Name","Plugin Output: 
Path : c:\program files (x86)\application\folder\service.exe
Used by services : application
File write allowed for groups : Users, Authenticated Users
Full control of directory allowed for groups : Users, Authenticated Users","At least one improperly configured Windows service may have a privilege escalation vulnerability.","At least one Windows service executable with insecure permissions was detected on the remote host. Services configured to use an executable with weak permissions are vulnerable to privilege escalation attacks.
An unprivileged user could modify or overwrite the executable with arbitrary code, which would be executed the next time the service is started. Depending on the user that the service runs as, this could result in privilege escalation.

This plugin checks if any of the following groups have permissions to modify executable files that are started by Windows services :

  - Everyone
    - Users
    - Domain Users
    - Authenticated Users","Ensure the groups listed above do not have permissions to modify or write service executables. Additionally, ensure these groups do not have Full Control permission to any directories that contain service executables.","http://www.nessus.org/u?e4e766b2","","8.4","","AV:L/AC:L/PR:N/UI:N/S:U/C:H/I:H/A:H","cpe:/o:microsoft:windows","","","Jul 11, 2029 06:48:20 CEST","Jul 11, 2029 06:48:20 CEST","N/A","N/A","",""
```

---

Edit: I think I found another way how to accomplish this and looking at it, it looks I tried to overdo it quite a bit.

```
# Doing cleanup, changing delimiters, renaming that one known column. All in one line.
$importCSV = 'C:\TEMP\sourceReport.csv'
(Get-Content -Path $importCSV | Where-Object {-not [string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($PSItem)}).Replace('","','";"').Replace"VerylongOldColumnName","ShortName") | Out-File -FilePath C:\TEMP\tmp1.csv

# Adding additional columns and exporting it all to result CSV.
Import-Csv -Path C:\TEMP\tmp1.csv -Delimiter ";" | Select-Object *, "Column1", "Column2" | Export-Csv -Path C:\TEMP\result.csv -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter ";"
```

Comment: the `Export-CSV` cmdlet expects an object with properties ... a string has ONE property - length. that means you will get a one-column CSV with `Length` for the header and the character count for the value. try it ... >>> `'qwerty asdfgh' | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation` <<<

Comment: How do you intend to replace column names without knowing the column names?

Comment: Is the entire point of this to rename one of the columns before you send it to Excel? Or do you start with some sort of malformed csv data or something? There may be better ways to accomplish what you're doing without reading and writing to the disk so much.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Good point there, but I have limited amount of columns that are the same, the amount of columns can vary though. Basically, columns with important must have data and some nice to have data, which user can add to the report, when creating the report.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician The entire point is that the source CSV is poorly created, with a lot of white spaces and commas in the data fields and also having comma as a separator. So I want to clean it first, change the separator to something else, so it wouldn't brake the structure of the CSV and then rename a specific column.
But leaving all that aside, it should be like that: I have a CSV and it has to become a nice looking spreadsheet. This is not going to happen with the initial source CSV, that I get.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey I actually understood the string thing in the end, but I don't understand why the output becomes a string and how do I force the whole output to become a structured semicolon delimited file again.

Comment: Please describe in more detail what you want to accomplish. Renaming known columns is a non-issue. You can do that via calculated properties. Do you want to do anything else than that? Remove particular columns for instance? If so, how do you identify them?

Comment: It may help if you show us the current CSV and below that the altered csv as you want to see it.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Please see the reply above, one I wrote to TheMadTechnician, for the core point of this activity.

I don't want to remove columns. Whatever columns the source CSV has, I will add a static set of columns to that.

I agree, renaming a column is not a problem, I just added it so you would see how it all goes. I'm not even sure adding the columns is a problem, since I know how to do that as well. Please read the reply, mentioned above.

Comment: @Theo I'm not sure it would help. I can't show you that this is how the source CSV looks like, because the whole point is that the source CSV can change and have anything there. Please read the reply above, one I wrote to TheMadTechnician. Hopefully it will help you understand better what I want to accomplish.

Comment: We cannot help you fix a format when you don't give us examples of the format(s) you want to fix.

Comment: Well, due to popular demand, I added a sample of the Source CSV.. one entry anyway. I hope this helps you somewhat.
As you can see, there's alot of wasted space all around in the Plugin Text column. Also, notice that field delimiters are commas and you will see commas in the Synopsis column.

Comment: @Ramil - why would you expect this `$($item.$($headers[$h]))` to give you anything other than a string? try tracing each level of that calculation and you will get the _value_ of a property, not an object with a value stored in a property.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey Short answer, I don't know. I can't tell what's causing this behavior. I'm pretty much experimenting.
I mayyybeee understood you.. not sure. I'll see if I can approach this somehow differently, without getting whatever is currently stored as property value (a string).

Comment: start by looking at what comes out of that bit of code ... from what i can tell by reading your post, it is the STRING that was in a property. at that point you have an object, yes. but it is a simple object with ONE property - length. that aint likely to be a thing you are all that interested in. in order for `Export-CSV` to work, it requires an object ...you have that, but it aint what you appear to want. you seem to wan the string value itself. you need to put that in a property OR send it out as plain text, not as a CSV file.

Comment: I could `Import-Csv` the example of the CSV just fine. It has fields that contain several lines, so as spreadsheet opened in Excel you need to go into the Cell properties and select [Wrap Text](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/wrap-text-in-a-cell-2a18cff5-ccc1-4bce-95e4-f0d4f3ff4e84) to show these lines.

Comment: Thanks all! It seems I found a way to accomplish all I wanted to do. (See the last update I did on my post)

Answer (score 0):

You should not simply replace `,` with `;` because the fields actually contain commas as in *..Additionally, ensure these groups ..* By replacing just like that, the field will get separated from the rest of its content and you'll end up with a mis-aligned csv.

The below approach will do what you want, leaving the structure of the csv file intact:

```
$importCSV    = 'C:\TEMP\sourceReport.csv'
$exportCSV    = 'C:\TEMP\result.csv'
$columnsToAdd = "Column1", "Column2"

# read the file as string array, not including empty lines
$content = Get-Content -Path $importCSV | Where-Object { $_ -match '\S' }
# replace the column header in the top line only
$content[0] = $content[0].Replace("VerylongOldColumnName", "ShortName")
# join the string array with newlines and convert that to an object with ConvertFrom-Csv
# add the columns to the object and export it using the semi-colon as delimiter
($content -join [Environment]::NewLine) | ConvertFrom-Csv | 
  Select-Object *, $columnsToAdd | 
  Export-Csv -Path $exportCSV  -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter ";"
```

Comment: I'm actually replacing "," with ";" (including quotes). Otherwise I would end up with worse of a mess than I started with and it has worked so far. I see that I had a typo in the example I pasted here.
     .Replace('","',";")
should've been
     .Replace('","','";"')